# Can't find Google Contacts in Gmail app

Tags: gmail

I have my Google Contacts on my PC. I have activated the sync feature in my Note 3 and synced my contacts with google. But when I open my Gmail app on my phone I can't even find the contacts link. I've searched everywhere for contacts and found nothing.
This is maddening!

Answer (score 2):

There is no option in the gmail app for viewing the contacts! You can access them through web.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the Contact or People (etc.) app to view contacts synced from Gmail.  The Gmail app does not include a Contacts section, though the search and compose features will populate contact suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, go to Settings and then Applications. Find GMail and set permissions to allow it to access your contacts.
Problem solved!

Comment: I don't think the Note 3 has marshmallow.